# claculate the number of days between two dates without libraries

Tags: java

I need to claculate the number of days between two dates without using any date or calendar classes provided by any library.

Here's my idea:

```
numberOfDays =  Math.abs((toYear - fromYear) * 365);
numberOfDays = numberOfDays + Math.abs((toMonth - fromMonth) * 12);
numberOfDays = numberOfDays + Math.abs((toDay - fromDay));
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Why without any libraries?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself so far? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Is this homework or for production code?  In the first case it is probably not appropriate to post a solution here.  In the second case: Just don't do it.  Do *use* a library.  Your implementation *will* miss out a corner case.

Comment: Thank you for being honest.  Unfortunately, in its current form, it will be hard to answer your question without doing the task you are supposed to do.  You should probably try some own solution first and if you have any specific problems with that, ask again.  Only my suggestion, good luck, anyway!

Comment: I managed to validate the dates using regexp however don't have an idea currently to do the calculation

Comment: so how do you pass the dates? as String?

Comment: Yes. See the edits I've made with my idea

Comment: @xgeorgekx Thanks, but it doesn't work still and you are using Date objects, assume Strings ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. How many days between the start date and the end of the month?
2. How many days in each full month until the end of the year?
3. How many days in each full year until the year of the end date (counting leap years)?
4. How many days in each full month until the last month?
5. How many days from the start of the last month until the end date?

Some of these numbers may be zero.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can do the following:

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.of(2014, Month.MARCH, 01), LocalDate.of(2014, Month.FEBRUARY, 15));
```

Comment: That would also meaning using a library function ;)

Comment: I implicitly read that as 3rd party libraries. Working completely without libraries might prove a little … tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do?

```
//get 2 random dates
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1 = new Date();
Date date2 = sdf.parse("2014-9-12");

final long msInADay = 24*60*60*1000; //turn a day to ms

//divide time difference by the ms of a day
int difference = (int)((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / msInADay); 

System.out.println(Math.abs(difference));//Math.abs so you can subtract dates in any order.
```

**EDIT** after updating your question:
You can do this:

```
static int calcDayDiff(int startY, int startM, int startD, int endY, int endM, int endD){
    int result = (startY - endY) * 365;
    result += (startM - endM) * 31;
    result += (startD - endD);
    return Math.abs(result);
}
```

Testing with: `System.out.println(calcDayDiff(2014,9,13,2013,8,12));` will print `397`

Note though that this is not a very good solution since not every month contains `31` days and not every year `365`. You can fix the month day difference by adding some simple logic inside the method to not always multiply by `31`. Since it's an assignment i guess you will be ok to consider every year having `365` days.

Comment: It prints 430 days for 01/09/00 to 30/12/1999 so not correct I'm afraid

Comment: for me it prints 243. are you sure you have passed the arguements correctly `calcDayDiff(2000,9,1,1999,12,30)`?

Comment: Yes. The reason this happens is because as i said i consider in the code all months to consist of 31 days. That's why this happens.

Comment: I don't think that logic that need to be added is that simple, have you got a quick solution for the problem?

Comment: Solved it using Julian day

Answer (score -1):

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2014, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        Date s = cal.getTime();

        Date e = new Date();

        System.out.println(days(s,e));
    }

    public static int days(Date start, Date end){
        double aTms = Math.floor(start.getTime() - end.getTime());
        return (int) (aTms/(24*60*+60*1000));
    }

}
```